# Laravel error on deployment: The [sqs] queue connection has not been configured

Tags: laravel

I have a fairly basic laravel site. Everytime Envoyer runs and deploys the site, I get a ton (150+) errors that say this:

```
InvalidArgumentException [...redacted project dir...]/current/artisan queue:work sqs --tries=5
The [sqs] queue connection has not been configured.
```

I'm not even using SQS so I have no idea where the error is coming from. Only deployment hooks I have in Envoyer that might be related are these:

[image]

My `.env` looks like this with things regarding the drivers and queue and such:

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

I'm lost here. Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you need to see anything else please let me know.

Comment: This error only ever happens during deployments, btw.

Comment: I would do 2 things: 1) remove all sqs parts from the config/queue (?) file, just let it give you exceptions, would be easier to trace. 2) I would add debug info in that schedule-monitor:sync command, so you can pinpoint when those sqs errors occur